# Copy records from one table to another without duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#A')  IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #A
IF object_id('tempdb..#B')  IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #B
CREATE TABLE #A (fname varchar(20), lname varchar(20))
CREATE TABLE #B (fname varchar(20), lname varchar(20))

INSERT INTO #A
SELECT 'Kevin', 'XP'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tammy', 'Win7'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Wes', 'XP'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Susan', 'Win7'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Kevin', 'Win7'


SELECT * FROM #A

INSERT INTO #B
SELECT a.fname, a.lname FROM #A a
WHERE a.fname NOT IN (SELECT fname from #B)

SELECT * FROM #B

DELETE FROM #B
INSERT INTO #B
SELECT a.fname, a.lname FROM #A a
LEFT OUTER JOIN #B b ON a.fname = b.fname
WHERE a.fname NOT IN (SELECT fname from #B)

SELECT * FROM #B
```

Both of these examples copy all 5 records to the new table.

I only want to see one unique fname so only one Kevin should show up.

Why don't these work, or is there a better way to do it?

It seems like such a simple thing.

Comment: but which `Kevin` should go into the new table?

Comment: Windows7 if both exist

Comment: Why Windows7?  Maybe you can post what the table should look like (and why)

Comment: I mean 'Win7'.  Rather than lname it would be better to have called it OS.  The query grabs a list of computer names  and their operating systems from Altiris, but if the old computer wasn't removed from the list, both XP and Win7 would show up.  I want to show the unique computer names and the most recent OS installed.  We can continue to call it lname for the example.

Comment: ;WITH List AS (
 Select distinct 
  fname,
  max(case lname
   when 'XP' then 1
   when 'Win7' then 2
   else 0
  end) as lname
  FROM #A
  GROUP BY fname
  )
 SELECT
  fname,
  case lname
   when 1 then 'XP'
   when 2 then 'Win7'
  end
 FROM List
 WHERE lname > 0

Comment: Are you prepared to hard-code a list of options that identify whether, say, Vista is newer than XP, Win7 is newer than Vista, etc. Or is it possible that you are also recording something more useful than the OS name, like date of install, etc.? Because what happens if someone replaces a machine with a newer one, but they both have Win7?

Comment: The only two enterprise operations are XP and Win7.  And Select DISTINCT would remove duplicates of same computername and os.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would create rows with unique fname and take Win7 if both Win7 and XP existed.

```
INSERT INTO #B
SELECT a.fname, MIN(a.lname) 
FROM #A a
GROUP BY a.fname
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize MIN() worked on strings as well.  In my comment above, I used a CASE statement to convert to numeric and then select the desired number.  This is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, given that `W` comes before `X` then you should be able to do

```
INSERT INTO #B
SELECT fname, lname
FROM (
    SELECT fname, lname,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fname ORDER BY lname) r
    FROM #A
) t
WHERE r=1
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb337/2)

Comment: I like this one, but the MIN(lname) is simpler. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question, why don't your queries work?

```
INSERT INTO #B
SELECT a.fname, a.lname FROM #A a
WHERE a.fname NOT IN (SELECT fname from #B)
```

This operation is evaluated in two different operations. In the first, the SELECT part of the query is executed. It returns a table. At such point #B is empty, hence, every tuple in #A will be part of this result. Then, once this result is computed, this result is inserted into #B. #B will end being a copy of #A.

The DBMS does not insert one tuple, and then re-evaluate the query for the next tuple of #A, as your question seems to imply. Insertions are always done AFTER the query has been completely evaluated.

if your goal is to insert into #B the tuples in #A without duplicates, there are many ways to do that. One of them is:

```
INSERT INTO #B SELECT distinct * from #A;
```

--dmg

Comment: The INSERT INTO #B SELECT DISTINCT still copied 5 records.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted distinct tuples, not distinct only by one attribute. I agree that the insert with the GROUP by is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just use DISTINCT over the select query :

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
(
     -- some big query
) x
```